# Vertically flipping PVRTC compressed image data

Tags: ios, opengl-es, compression, textures, pvrtc

I have some PVRTC 4bpp image data that needs to be flipped vertically in-place without decompression. The code I have written is mostly working but the flip currently introduces small artefacts and I'm unsure exactly why.

The PVRTC flip code first moves the 8-byte 4x4 compression blocks to their flipped position as calculated by the TwiddleUV() function from PVRTDecompress.cpp in the PowerVR SDK. This part appears to be correct.

Second, the code iterates through all the 8-byte compression blocks reversing the order of the second 4 bytes which contain the 4x4 modulation data stored in 2bpp. The first 4 bytes of the block contains color data which is left unchanged.

This seems to be very close to correct, but it leaves small artefacts in the flipped image that weren't there in the original and which manifest mostly as small greyish horizontal lines. If the flipping code is run twice then the artefacts go away and the image is unchanged from the original.

Can anyone with some PVRTC experience explain what else needs to be done to flip the compressed image data? I think the problem may be to do with the flipping of modulation data, but my forays into the PVRTC documentation haven't yielded the answer at this stage.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you just invert your texture coordinates? Why do you need to invert the texture data itself?

Comment: @BradLarson: I wondered that too, but assumed there must be a good reason.

Comment: @BradLarson: You certainly could invert the texture coordinates, or flip the image prior to compressing it, I was interested in doing it 'manually' for use in some offline texture processing steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this a bit easier to understand, you need to know the way PVRTC decodes the data as it's a bit different to block-based schemes like ETC1 or S3TC/DXTC.  For simplicity I'll only describe the 4bpp variant.

PVRTC consists of 2 low-resolution 15/16bpp images, A and B, that are 1/4 * 1/4 the resolution of the final texture, along with a full-resolution, but 2bpp modulation image. To 'logically' decode a texel, XY, the A and B images are *bilinearly* upscaled to the target resolution, and then the resulting colours, Axy and Bxy are blended according to the pixel in the modulation image. To make the decoding simpler in hardware, the A and B images are interleaved with the modulation data at the rate of 1 pixel from each with 16 from the modulation data, into 64-bit words.

Now, the reason it's not flipping exactly using just bit shuffling is because the 4x4 bilinear upscale is slightly offset from the centres of 4x4 texels (I think the reasons are described in the Graphics Hardware 2003 paper [linked from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PVRTC)). I expect the only thing you could do is actually evaluate each pixel and then after doing the flip of the bilinear colours, work out which of the four possibilities is actually the closest. In a way, it'd be a recompression, but it should be relatively quick.

Comment: I think you're onto something regarding the offsets, looking at figure 5 in that paper it would suggest that all the modulation data needs to be moved by one row. I'll give this a go and see if it helps. If at all possible I'd like to avoid evaluating and then recompressing/recreating modulation values, as this would make the vertical flip take longer than a full decompression! Thanks.

Comment: I can't see that moving the modulation data by one row will help at all. Whatever scheme you use, in general it'll be an approximation to the original compressed data. I believe you will either need to adjust the modulation values to suit the relocated bilinear representatives or try to adjust the bilinear colours themselves so that it's a best fit. I think it'd be easier to tweak the vertex or fragment shader and use the hardware to do the flip <shrug>

Comment: What I meant to suggest was to offset/realign the two low res images vertically by the equivalent of one row in the uncompressed image, or 1/4 pixel in the low res image, in an attempt to fix the vertical alignment. I thought this because the flip introduces a number of one-pixel high horizontal lines ~7-8 pixels above hard white/black transitions in in the original image, and it's really only near these kind of hard transition areas that the flip has visual problems.

Comment: So maybe it ends up with an off by one problem in the upscaled low resolution image data, and resampling the low res image data by 1/4 pixel might fix it. I'm not sure if that makes sense, but at any rate it would alter the appearance as well, so, as you said originally there isn't a way to vertically flip the image in-place without altering it at least subtly. Thanks very much for your help with this.

Comment: I still don't know why you can't use a shader to modify the texture coordinates, but if you do want to flip the texture (and given that I'm from the antipodes, maybe it makes sense :)) you could compute some new bilinear rep colours for an 'offset of 1 pixel' using this three tap filter: RepNewCentre =  -0.068 * RepAbove + 0.818 * Centre + 0.25 * RepBelow.  You'd need to do that for all the channels.